# mac: How to mount ejected external hdd again

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, mount

I've used my WD My Book 1TB for quite some time now. I always simply unplug it without officially 'ejecting' it. However, yesterday I did eject it (the partitions) before unplugging it.

However, now, when i reconnect the hdd, it does not show the drives. It only shows the WD SmartWare partition (which is empty btw). The rest doesn't start.

Does anyone know how to mount an unmounted disk? thx in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app`. You should see the device and it's volumes which you might be able to mount.

If you've been unplugging it without properly unmounting it (*not* recommended!) there is a chance it's become corrupted.

`Disk Utility` will also let you check the volumes for any corruption - select the appropriate volume and in the "First Aid" tab click "Verify Disk".

And, as an admin user, you could look in `/var/log/system.log` for any clues around the time the disk is connected.

Comment: Yeah, yanking the drive like that is definitely asking for corruption and data loss.