# How to make recognise an improperly ejected disk?

Tags: external-hard-drive, macbook, disk-utility

Earlier, the external backup disk was not mounting on my Macbook automatically after plugging in to USB-C port via an adaptor for USB. It wasn't in the disk list in Finder.

I succeeded to mount from Disk Utility where it was visible, but not mounted.

Following that, while copying files, I accidentally touched the adaptor and the disk was disconnected and ejected.

The disk is no more recocognized by my Mac. I run

```
diskutil list
```

in Terminal and it is not listed.

However, and at my surprise, it can be visible, but not mounted on an other Macbook on which I tested. I run First Aid, and it was OK, not even corrupted. I wonder why it is not mounting automatically.

Is there a way to make it recognise back by my Macbook?

P.S. I just saw [this question](https://superuser.com/q/102572/1140054) but the situation is slightly different

Comment: In Disk Utility, hit CMd/2 then select the device rather than the volume. Test again. Also, what format is the device/volume? GUID/HFS or APFS, or is it MBR/ExFAT or similar? Did you reboot the Mac yet?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have no idea what is CMd/2 and where to hit it :( I already tried to do "View/Show all Devices", only internal hard drive is shown. I rebooted my Macbook with all the modes that I know - Diagnostics, Safe, Recovery, no difference. The disk is HFS in my memory, I don't have access to the other Mac(my daughter's) to check, but could do a bit later

Comment: Cmd ⌘ and the number 2 - but you already found it, show all devices. Perhaps try a different port. [Did you use the same adaptor when you tested it on the other Mac? It's a possibility]

Comment: I tested with the same adaptor(I don't have an other one on hand) and on all 4 ports

Comment: Check that same adapter on the other computer when you get the chance. If you've established the drive works & the ports work, that's your next elimination process.

Comment: I already did the test on the other computer(same disk, same adaptor) and all is good. On mine, with the same adaptor neither of ports work. However, all ports work with an other disk, same adaptor

Comment: I wonder if there is a log where I can read the reason for rejection. Or a config file where this disk is blacklisted

Comment: It wasn't 'rejected' it sufferd a hard-fail communication break - that could kill the drive, the USB port, or the adaptor. It's not blacklisted anywhere, the Mac would try to mount it if it could.